# Programming FireWire / IEEE 1394 under Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, firewire

I am using **libraw1394** library which provides direct access to the IEEE 1394 bus in Linux. It is very easy to use and I wonder if there is **something like libraw1394** for Windows?

And generally how can I access the IEEE 1394 bus in Windows? Is DDK the only way to do it?

**UPD.** I found VHPD1394. A special device driver, which provides Win32 applications with direct access to IEEE 1394 devices. The documentation states it can be used with any kind of IEEE 1394 device, enabling application developers to control devices without having to develop a kernel-mode WDM driver. The programming interface supports C, C++ and Delphi. **Unfortunately it is not free!**

**UPD.** Freddie Witherden is in the process of porting his FireWire library to Windows: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/36228727/writing-a-1394-interface-driver.aspx

The question he asked here ([Including a Windows DDK Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735087/including-a-windows-ddk-header/4822645#4822645)) contains some ideas of using a DeviceIo calls in order to access the FireWire bus.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 1394 driver using the [Microsoft 1394 WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Well, I don't feel like it makes sense to write a whole driver and a userspace API.